# Using where and orderby with different parameter firebase javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Im trying to make this simple query work with firebase on my nodejs server

```
admin.firestore().collection("articles").where("postDate", "<=", mintime).orderBy("views", "desc").limit(10)
```

Here: `postDate` is in a date format and `views` is an integer.

I get the following error

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Error: 3 INVALID_ARGUMENT: inequality filter property and first sort order must be the same: postDate and views

The idea of a query is to get the articles that have been posted within a timespan, and sorted by views to get the most relevant articles. The where(...) and orderBy(...) statement works fine by them selfs but breaks together. Is this not possible to do something like that in firebase, if so how?

Comment: The error message is telling you it's not possible. You can apply ordering in client code if you want, but you will not be able to use a limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll first need to order on `postDate`:

```
admin.firestore().collection("articles")
  .orderBy("postDate")
  .where("postDate", "<=", mintime)
  .orderBy("views", "desc")
  .limit(10)
```