# where and orderBy - Firebase conflict

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks

I'm using react firebase hooks and trying to query by using `orderBy` and `where` selectors.
I'm not getting any error, just empty records. Here's a code:

```
  const queryRef = query(
    getFromFirestore("/clients"), // My custom db/config getter
    orderBy("archived"),
    where("archived", "==", false),
    orderBy("createdAt", "desc"),
    limit(5)
  );

  const [clients = [], loading, error] = useCollectionData(queryRef, {
    snapshotListenOptions: { includeMetadataChanges: true },
  });
```

Everything is ok until I'm using `where` and `orderBy` together. If I'll remove one of those - then firebase returns me the correct records

I've used the suggestion from this post: [Using where and orderby with different parameter firebase javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63564872/using-where-and-orderby-with-different-parameter-firebase-javascript) - but it still not working.

EDIT: Here's a screen from DB
[image]

Comment: What exactly are you expecting?  We can't see your source data, so we don't know if this is actually the right behavior or not. If you edit the question to show actual document data, we could tell you whether or not your expectations are correct.

Comment: I have a Clients which all by default have a flag: `archived: false` - I want to pick only those clients and sort them by another field: `createdAt` - which is a date (isoDate)

Comment: Right, so it would be helpful if you show that actual data.  Take screenshots, or show the code that added it, or something we can reproduce.  We also can't see how your are observe the results.  We can't see how your chosen to output the results of the query.  That could be a problem as well.

Comment: You have two orderBy clauses.  Which one is causing the problem?

Comment: Why are you ordering by `archived`?

Comment: @DougStevenson     orderBy("createdAt", "desc")

Comment: @DaveNewton - I've used suggestion from post which I Linked - I don't need this orderBy claus

Comment: Where is your code that checks for errors on the query?  How are you observing the results that are unexpected?

Comment: I don't have any I'm newbie in firebase

Comment: Keep in mind that if there is a problem with your query, the error message would tell you what the problem is, then you could do searches on that string to find more.  Ignoring errors is a bad idea, no matter your level of expertise.

Comment: "it still not working" is almost impossible to work with. We'll need to know what you expected the code to do, what it did instead, and why your expectation was better than the latter. --- If you're not getting any results with the additional clause, it's probably because you didn't create the necessary composite index. Catch any errors and check them to find if that's the case, in which case the error message will also include a link that allows you to create the necessary index with a single click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution. I dint know that `error` object can contains such an info - about wrong query or something around query. Anyway - firestore throws this error:

`FirebaseError: The query requires an index. That index is currently building and cannot be used yet. See its status here:`

Rest of error message is an exact link to our firebase console/config where you can add almost automatically - missing index. Google Cloud needs some time to build and index. After this time - everything works well.

The thread can be closed.